# Android - How to get an image address for uploading a server

Tags: java, android

```
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
in.close();

imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
```

How do I change "img" to an image address for uploading the server?

Thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: You use data.getData() again. You have a fine uri there.

Comment: like change an image to a url?